# Jquery scrollTo only works once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a problem with ScrollTo, my problem is that it works fine the first time i click on a link but not after when i click on a diffrent link.

Other information.
The elements i want to scrollto, is first gonna show up when i click a button, then all the elements gets animated and shows up on the page.

See below code

[see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ts7OF.jpg)

```
        $(document).ready(function ($) {

        $("ul.sitecheck-navigation li.seo-optimering-sitechek").click(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        scrollPageTo($('.meta-sitechek'));
        });

        $("ul.sitecheck-navigation li.newstuff-sitechek").click(function (event) {
        scrollPageTo($('.newstuff-sitechek'));
        });

        function scrollPageTo($target) {
        var scrollHeight = document.body.scrollHeight;
                $(window).stop(true).scrollTo($target, {
        duration: 600,
                progress: function() {
                // If the page scroll height changes, scroll afresh to the shifted target
                if (scrollHeight !== document.body.scrollHeight) scrollPageTo($target);
                }
        });
                return false;
        }

        });
```

It works fine when i click on a link for the first time, it scrolls to my div with the correct class.

But when i click again on a diffrent link, it only scrolls about 10px down when it should go up.

Anybody have any idea how that could be?

Comment: Why are you binding `ready` handlers within `click` handlers?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean Frédéric, do u think thats why its not working after the first time i click a link? What do u mean by binding Ready handlers within Click Handlers?

Comment: I was referring to the `$(function() {` everywhere (that's the only only thing obvious to me since your code is poorly indented, sorry to say). Anyway, these are shortcuts to `$(document).ready()` and although it means the handlers will run, that's a pretty strong hint you should spend more time understand that code.

Comment: Thanks for that :) I have changed it know, but still it only works once, do u have any idea what could be the problem.

Comment: It's really hard to tell without a [mcve]. Could you provide one? Without one I am left to conjectures like *`$(window).stop()` probably doesn't work like you expect it to* and *if one of `li.seo-optimering-sitechek` and `li.newstuff-sitechek` is a descendant of the other, the clicks will propagate up and all hell will break loose*.

Comment: I just added a image of the links and the divs i whant to scrollto hope that helps :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved thanks Frédéric. It was my calling off divs there where wrong after i added .list-result to my scrollto it works :)